# Django Threaded Commenting System

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

(and sorry for my english)

I am learning Python and Django. Now, my challange is developing threaded generic comment system. There is two models, Post and Comment.

-Post can be commented.

-Comment can be commented. (endless/threaded)

-Should not be a n+1 query problem in system. (No matter how many comments, should not increase the number of queries)

My current models are like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    child = generic.GenericRelation(
        'Comment',
        content_type_field='parent_content_type',
        object_id_field='parent_object_id'
    )

class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()

    child = generic.GenericRelation(
        'self',
        content_type_field='parent_content_type',
        object_id_field='parent_object_id'
    )

    parent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    parent_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    parent = generic.GenericForeignKey(
        "parent_content_type", "parent_object_id")
```

Are my models right? And how can i get all comment (with hierarchy) of post, without n+1 query problem?

Note: I know mttp and other modules but I want to learn this system.

---

Edit: I run "`Post.objects.all().prefetch_related("child").get(pk=1)`" command and this gave me post and its child comment. But when I wanna get child command of child command a new query is running. I can change command to `...prefetch_related("child__child__child...")...` then still a new query running for every depth of child-parent relationship. Is there anyone who has idea about resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all comments on a post with a single query then it would be good to have every comment link to the asssociated post. You can use a separate link to indicate the parent comment.

Basically:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment')
    # link to all comments, even children of comments

class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    child_comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment')
    # You may find it easier to organise these into a tree 
    # if you use a parent_comment ForeignKey. That way the
    # top level comments have no parent and can be easily spotted.

Post.objects.all().select_related('comments').get(pk=1)
```

The many to many in this takes [a little extra work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to create the association, as it uses an intermediate table. If you want a pure [one to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) then you need a `ForeignKey` on the `Comment` but then you are restricted to a `prefetch_related` instead of a `select_related`, which then involves an extra database hit.

This is also better in that you do not have an untyped foreign key reference (your `PostitiveIntegerField`).

You then need to arrange the comments into a tree structure, but that is outside the scope of your question.